# XML Path SQL not working in SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, for-xml-path

fThe SQL below has been working for years in a 2008 SSIS package:

```
SELECT 
BofAAcctNumber AS 'td'
,''
,ReferenceNumber AS 'td'
,''
,CheckNumber AS 'td'
,''
,CheckAmount AS 'td'
FROM dbo.bai2_CheckStatementError
    WHERE BenefitID IS NULL
FOR XML PATH('tr')
```

In SSMS it returns expected results as below

```html
<tr><td>999999999</td><td>88888888888</td><td>123456</td><td>999.00</td></tr>
```

Using an Execute SQL Task (Single Row into a string variable) in 2012 SSIS it kicks a DBNull error: The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::strHTMLTable" differs from the current variable type (String)

Any criticism or comments welcome, thank you.

Comment: Is this in an Execute SQL Task? How are you assigning the value to the variable?

Comment: Yes. Execute SQL task set to Single Row into a String Variable, thank you

Comment: In the 'Result Set' section, what is in the 'Result Name' field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify 'Result' in the 'Result Name' field in the 'Result Set' section and use:

```
SELECT
    CAST
        (
            (
                SELECT 
                    BofAAcctNumber AS 'td'
                    ,''
                    ,ReferenceNumber AS 'td'
                    ,''
                    ,CheckNumber AS 'td'
                    ,''
                    ,CheckAmount AS 'td'
                FROM dbo.bai2_CheckStatementError
                WHERE BenefitID IS NULL
                FOR XML PATH('tr')
            )
        AS nvarchar) Result -- or nvarchar(x) - as Ann L. points out, nvarchar will truncate the string to 30 characters
```

(You could also use `varchar` if appropriate.)

Comment: Thank you, Chris. That worked. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem - please mark the answer as correct if it is working. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to truncate the xml output to 30 characters, and mine's going to be in the vicinity of 50,000 characters, so `varchar(8000)` won't cut it. Is there any other way around SSIS not liking `(max)`?

Comment: @AnnL., I guess it would depend on what you will be doing with the variable - one thing I would definitely try if appropriate is setting the variable's type as `object` and not `string` - is that useful to you?

Comment: I found a solution: change the result set type to XML, and assign it to a variable of type String. Then I can put the following code in a SQL Task or data source:  `DECLARE @idList varchar(max) = ?;   DECLARE @xmlList xml = CONVERT(xml, @idList);` and query the xml variable I just created with `nodes()` and `value()` to use it as if it were a table.

Comment: @ChrisMack I appreciate your replying! Especially to a comment on a 4 year old question! Thank you!

Comment: @AnnL., you're welcome! Glad you got it sorted.